# Смысл скобок в фразе: "о состоянии здоровья (получении инвалидности)"

Tags: семантика, смысл

Какой смысл имеют скобки в данной фразе?

Означает ли фраза: "Сообщить об изменении сведений о состоянии здоровья (получении инвалидности)", что требуется сообщить только о получении инвалидности?

Answer (score 2):

Нужен контекст. Может, там дальше, например, перечень идет на две страницы )) А так, можно только предположить, что имеется в виду все же инвалидность, если документ выдавался-получался в связи с ней.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%83%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82_%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8
алаверды

Comment: Ну и что? Демонстрация навыка быстро скакать по интернетам — не более.

Comment: Ответ неправильный. Не это.

Comment: Ну уж не вам судить — правильный или неправильный. Вопрос задавали не вы.

Comment: Но отвечали-то вы мне. Вот неправильео и ответили. Думайте дальше.

Comment: Отвечала я не вам.

Comment: А простите, это Вы, типа, "тихо сам с обою, левою рукою":

>Ну и что? Демонстрация навыка быстро скакать по интернетам — не более.

ЗЫ Обожаю дразнить надутых снобов. Особенно тех, кто думает, что он в теме. Это я не Вам отвечаю, если что.

Comment: Marina-ja, извините за некорректность вопроса, контекст именно этот. Это мне судей надо убедить, что сообщать надо не только про инвалидность, но и о серьёзном улучшении состояния здоровья. А вот опереться пока не на что (в том смысле, что не могу представить доказательства своего довода).

Comment: Для суда — это серьезно. Думаю, имеет смысл обратиться за лингвистической экспертизой.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 2):

> Требуется сообщить только о получении инвалидности

Нет, конечно. **Об изменении состояния здоровья - и особо о получении инвалидности, если таковое было**.
Это вариант канцелярского стиля, когда в скобках перечисляют возможные варианты. Смысл в том, что таким образом - по мнению пишущего - убирают двусмысленность во фразе "состоянии здоровья ИЛИ получении инвалидности".
Можно спорить, насколько сам по себе этот прием удачен, но означает он именно это.

> Это мне судей надо убедить, что сообщать надо не только про инвалидность, но и о серьёзном улучшении состояния здоровья.

Бесполезно. В этих вопросах суд у нас всегда прав. Но если вопрос об экспертизе действительно встанет, то это сюда [ГЛЭДИС](http://www.rusexpert.ru/). И не забудьте первоисточник (сам Закон) изучить на предмет понимания отдельных терминов.
~~~~~

Я вот пока суть да дело обратил внимание на хитрость формулировки.
"Об изменении сведений о семейном положении, образовании, состоянии здоровья".
Не об изменении семейного положения, образования, состояния здоровья, а об изменении **сведений**. Изменение сведений о состоянии здоровья(!!!). Что оно такое значит - бог его значит, но вояки рулят... Помучаетесь еще с экспертизой...

Comment: Спасибо! Контекст именно этот. А где можно почитать, ссылку можно?

Comment: Я имею ввиду ссылку на этот вариант канцелярского стиля. К сожалению, самостоятельно не нашёл.

Comment: На учебник канцелярита? Это вряд ли.
А в качестве примера -

>23. «Семейное положение (женат, холост, вдов), перечислите членов семьи и укажите их возраст. Если вдов, разведен или женат вторично, укажите фамилию, имя и отчество прежней жены (мужа)…» Ну, какое дело проектному бюро до жены, умершей двадцать лет назад? Какое отношение это может иметь к проекту гостиницы?   

Рыбаков, "Дети Арбата"

Comment: Спасибо!!!

Comment: Да, прочитал. Всем огромное спасибо за помощь!